# Finding all subsets of four numbers that sum to 1

Tags: python, permutation

I am trying to compute all subsets ("allocations") of four rational numbers which sum to 1.0 in python. 
For example valid allocations would be [0.2,0.2,0.4,0.2] or [1.0,0,0,0] or [0.35,0.35,0.3,0]. Repetition matters. By that I mean for example [0.2,0.2,0.4,0.2] and [0.4,0.2,0.2,0.2] are both valid allocations.

There would obviously be a tremendously large number of subsets so to make this smaller I would like to specify a "precision". For example having a precision of 0.05 would allow for each element in a subset to change by k*"precision" where k is an integer between 0 and 20 in this case.

So what I've tried. It successfully works if I simply perform a 4X For loop stepping in each for loop by the "precision" and checking if it is a valid allocation (i.e. if it sums to 1.0). This works but I was hoping to find a more efficient way. As people like to say, more pythonic.

Comment: What approaches have you considered so far?

Comment: @MikePelley See above. I edited

Comment: I suggest restricting the values to integers. Otherwise you are using floating point, and you are going to experience lots of problems due to inexact representations.  Numbers that appear to sum to another number will in fact be off by some small amount.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `r` (the reciprocal of the precision) is an integer (otherwise no solution is possible), the problem is equivalent to finding all 4-tuples of non-negative integers that sum to r. That's equivalent to choosing 3 numbers from the first r+3 integers and taking the run lengths of the unchosen numbers between the chosen ones and the ends. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)

With that, the solution is straightforward in Python using `itertools.combinations`.

```
from __future__ import division
import itertools

r = 20

for x in itertools.combinations(range(r + 3), 3):
    print x[0]/r, (x[1]-x[0]-1)/r, (x[2]-x[1]-1)/r, (r+2-x[2])/r
```

Comment: If I set r = 100, which basically means that we can change each element by a multiple of 1% (0.01), I get this invalid allocation 0.0 0.19 0.1 0.71. Any idea?

Comment: Why is that invalid? Perhaps I don't understand the problem, but it looks like each item is a multiple of 0.01 and they sum to 1.

Comment: They add to 1.01, I believe. 0 0.18 0.1 0.71 would be valid for example.

Comment: @bazzoli92 it looks like you've tainted a great answer with bad math, even Unix dc says 0.0 0.19 0.1 0.71 + + + -> 1.00

Comment: @bazzoli92 you're sanity checking the lower (1/100) digit by eye and have confused 0.1 with 0.01?